# Was bedeutet hier “hetzbereit”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich weiß, was „hetzen“ und „bereit,“ bedeutet, aber ist dieses Wort ein Adjektiv? “Ready to hound” oder “ready to harass?” Keine Ergebnisse in Duden.

> Es sind nicht nur die echten Nazis mit ihrem Hitlergruß, die in Chemnitz **hetzbereit** marschieren. Unsere Gesellschaft erlebt eine Konsensverschiebung nach rechts. <sup>[Harald Welzer, Zeit Online 30.8.2018](https://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/2018-08/rechtsruck-gesellschaft-rechte-hetze)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Das Adjektiv »hetzbereit« lässt sich als »zu Hetze bereit sein« oder als »zu hetzen bereit sein / bereit sein, zu hetzen« erklären.

Unter dem Stichwort »[-bereit](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_bereit)« publiziert der Duden folgende Bedeutungen:

> **1.** drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven aus, dass die beschriebene Person
> oder Sache zu etwas bereit, gerüstet ist
>
> Beispiele: *funktions-, reise-,sprungbereit*
>
> **2.** drückt in Bildungen mit Verben (Verbstämmen) aus, dass
> etwas sofort getan werden kann
>
> Beispiele: *abruf-, fahr-, startbereit*
>
> **3.** drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven aus, dass die beschriebene Person
> den Willen zu etwas hat
>
> Beispiele: *dialog-, leistungs-, risikobereit*

Sich auf eine Bedeutung festzulegen, ist in diesem Fall recht schwierig, am ehesten würde ich mich wohl für **1.** entscheiden. Sollte der Autor **3.** meinen, könnte er »hetzwillig« verwenden.

Answer (score 7):

Wenn du ein Wort nicht im Duden oder einem anderen Wörterbuch finden kannst, bedeutet das nicht viel. Vor allem dann nicht, wenn das Wort etwas länger ist.

Die deutsche Sprache ist voll mit Komposita, also mit zusammengesetzten Wörtern, und es gibt keine prinzipiellen Verbote, die beschränken würden, welche Wörter man zu Komposita zusammenfügen darf. Wenn sich der Sinn eines bisher noch nie verwendeten Kompositums aus dem Kontext, in dem das Wort verwendet wird, von einem Muttersprachler relativ zweifelsfrei erahnen lässt, reicht das aus, um das Kompositum zu legitimieren.

Dazu muss man nur *mitdenkbereit* und *innovationsoffen* sein, dann bereiten einem *Neuwortkompositionen*, die in keinem *Standardlexikon* stehen, keinerlei Schwierigkeiten.

Allerdings sollte man beim aktiven Gebrauch solcher *Wortneuschöpfungen* vorsichtig sein. Wenn es etablierte Wörter mit der gewünschten Bedeutung gibt, und wenn man keinen besonderen Grund hat, etwas Neues zu erfinden, sollte man lieber beim Bewährten bleiben. Allerdings kann man das niemandem zwingend vorschreiben. Daher solltest du wissen, dass solche neuen Komposita vielleicht manchmal zwar ein stilistischer Grenzfall sind, aber dass weder grammatisch noch orthographisch irgend etwas dagegen spricht.

Comment: Schon Mark Twain beklagte, dass in deutschen Zeitungen Wörter vorkommen, die vom Autor des Artikels neu geschaffen wurden und die in keinem Wörterbuch enthalten sind.

Comment: Mark Twain, was für ein Spießer!